# Spawning Multiple Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I'm not sure this is possible but this is what I'm trying to do. I have a call to a database that returns a promise. In the `then` I want to iterate over the results and spawn a new promise for each row to make an HTTP request. It's performing all of the HTTP requests but I am not able to chain a then for each request. Here's what I have tried:

**Attempt 1**

```
userDao.getBitbucketInfoForUser(token.id, cohortId)
    // Get Bitbucket information and make clones
    .then((teams) => {
        for(const team of teams) {
            console.log('Clone repo ' + sourceRepo + ' for Team-' + team.teamNumber);
            return makeFork(gitInfo, sourceRepo, team);
        }
    })
    .then((result) => {
        const team = result.team;
        console.log('Wait for Team ' + team + ' repo');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        response.status(error.status).json(error).end()
    });
```

I realized right away that this was dumb because I was returning and breaking out of my loop. So I went to this:

**Attempt 2**

```
userDao.getBitbucketInfoForUser(token.id, cohortId)
    // Get Bitbucket information and make clones
    .then((teams) => {
        for(const team of teams) {
            console.log('Clone repo ' + sourceRepo + ' for Team-' + team.teamNumber);
            makeFork(gitInfo, sourceRepo, team)
                .then((result) => Promise.resolve(result));
        }
    })
    .then((result) => {
        const team = result.team;
        console.log('Wait for Team ' + team + ' repo');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        response.status(error.status).json(error).end()
    });
```

This time it went through and made all of the calls in `makeFork` but only ran the `then` once. Next I tried this:

**Attempt 3**

```
userDao.getBitbucketInfoForUser(token.id, cohortId)
    // Get Bitbucket information and make clones
    .then((teams) => {
        for(const team of teams) {
            console.log('Clone repo ' + sourceRepo + ' for Team-' + team.teamNumber);
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(makeFork(gitInfo, sourceRepo, team)));
        }
    })
    .then((result) => {
        const team = result.team;
        console.log('Wait for Team ' + result + ' repo');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        response.status(error.status).json(error).end()
    });
```

This resulted in the exact same behavior as Attempt 2. Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: How about promise all?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: I saw that but it didn't really look like the thing I want. it takes some interable and calls the then once they're all resolved. I may need that down the line but not I want to act on each HTTP call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. As noted by other users `Promise.all` is exactly what you want, even if you need to act on each element individually.

```
userDao.getBitbucketInfoForUser(token.id, cohortId)
    // Get Bitbucket information and make clones
    .then((teams) => {
        // Act on each element individually.
        const teamPromises = teams.map((team) => {
            return makeFork(gitInfo, sourceRepo, team).then((result) => {
                const team = result.team;
                console.log('Wait for Team ' + team + ' repo');
            });
        });
        // Then resolve everything.
        return Promise.all(teamPromises);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        response.status(error.status).json(error).end()
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is ideal for your use case. It will wait for all your `makeFork` promises to resolve before continuing the chain. It will also fail as soon as one of the promises fails and correctly propagate the error to your `catch`.

Since you said in the comment that you "want to act on each HTTP call", this can mean one of two things. You either want to:

1. First obtain all results of the HTTP request, then process each of these results in some way, then continue down the promise chain.
2. Process each result as it resolves, then proceed down the promise chain once all results are processed.

The first option further branches depending if the result processing is:

- *asynchronous (returns a promise)*: you'll need to use another `Promise.all` to process all the results from `makeFork`.
- *synchronous (doesn't return a promise)*: you just loop over the results obtained after initial `Promise.all` is resolved and do the processing there.

Here's how the code could look for all cases:

**1.** *First resolve all requests, then process all results, then continue down the chain*

```
userDao.getBitbucketInfoForUser(token.id, cohortId)
  .then(teams => Promise.all(
    teams.map(team =>
      makeFork(gitInfo, sourceRepo, team)
    )
  ))

  // the next `then` will get called once all makeFork requests are successfully resolved

  // use this if you have async processing of team results
  .then(arrayOfResultsForEachMakeForkRequest => Promise.all(
    arrayOfResultsForEachMakeForkRequest.map(processTeamResult)
  ))

  // or use this (without Promise.all) if you have sync processing of team results
  .then(arrayOfResultsForEachMakeForkRequest => 
    arrayOfResultsForEachMakeForkRequest.map(processTeamResult)
  )

  // either way, now you have your processed results
  // this part of the chain will be reached after every result is obtained and processed
  .then(processedResults => {
    // ...
  })
  .catch(reason => {
    // this will get called if any of the promises in any part of the chain fails
  })
```

**2.** *Process each result as it comes in, then proceed down the chain once all results are processed*

```
userDao.getBitbucketInfoForUser(token.id, cohortId)
  .then(teams => Promise.all(
    teams.map(team =>
      makeFork(gitInfo, sourceRepo, team)
        .then(processTeamResult) // <-- the code will behave the same no matter if `processTeamResult` returns a promise that will resolve to a value or the value itself
    )
  ))

  // this part of the chain will be reached after every result is obtained and processed
  .then(processedResults => {
    // ...
  })
  .catch(reason => {
    // this will get called if any of the promises in any part of the chain fails
  })
```

You can use the same function you had in your code as a test for `processTeamResult`:

```
const processTeamResult = (result) => {
  console.log('Wait for Team ' + result.team + ' repo');
  return result;
}
```

As a side note, your last 2 attempts do the exact same thing, which is that they both redundantly attach another promise to `makeFork`, except one does it before and the other after. In either case, the overall chain isn't affected because you're not returning a promise from the `then` callback.